# Conditionally change year in DOB

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a 'date' column which I cleaned to change all dates to the same format (date/month/year).

Since originally some dates ended with the year being two digits eg. `2/7/95`, they got converted to `02/07/2095`. However, I need to change the year of those dates that are 21st century, to 20th century, so `20yy` -> `19yy`.

This is my function at the moment:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Input -> Function output -> Expected output:

```
 07/12/02  -> 07/12/2002 -> 07/12/1902
 07-Sep-09 -> 07/09/2019 -> 07/09/1919
```

How do I:

- Extract the Year section after function
- Check whether it needs to be changed

  - Change Year if yes

I've tried this:

```
year= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year 
if year.any() > 2000:
    subset['date']= pd.Timedelta(pd.offsets.year(1000))
```

Comment: what's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: It doesn't change anything- so 21st century dates are unchanged

Comment: @Yuca: the issue is with 'yy' two-year-digits format being converted to 19yy, not 20yy. The OP should be using '%y' format spec for two-year, not '%Y'. But the output would still need fixup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this...

```
year= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year 
if year.any() > 2000:
    subset['date']= pd.Timedelta(pd.offsets.year(1000))
```

It seems you'd like something like

```
subset['date'] = subset['date'].mask(subset['date'].dt.year > 2000, 
                                     subset['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=100))
```

Which would, for the ones that are above the year 2000, subtract 100 years from the date. And in cases where the condition (parameter 1) fails, keep the original value.

Note that this answer assumes that `subset['date']` is a Pandas datetime series.

Comment: What if it's an obj?

Comment: Don't convert it to `str` like you do in the first code snippet you have then. Do that conversion later. You'd only use a date object if your time doesn't fit in the ~500 year range of Pandas datetimes anyway, and the fact you invoke `pd.to_datetime` implies that your data can be turned into datetime in the first place.

Comment: @QWERTY, you should note that I accidentally put in a `>=` instead of `>` for 2000, if you used this, please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

`dt.strftime` converts datetime to other formats, but then dtype of column will be object (string).

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: 
             x - pd.DateOffset(years=100) if x.year >= 2000 else x)
```

If you want the same datetime formatting again the use

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: 
             x - pd.DateOffset(years=100) if x.year >= 2000 else x).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Why do you offset years by 100 and not 1000?

Comment: because the difference between 2002 and 1902 is 100 not 1000. But again its up to you what you want

Answer (score -1):

**Updated for one line solution.**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['07/12/02','07/09/19']})
df['date']=np.where( pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year>2000,( pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.DateOffset(years=100)), pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
```

Comment: 1999 turns into 1899

Comment: @ifly6 let me fix it.

Comment: @ifly6     I have updated it for a one line solution!

Comment: Your answer now just seems incredibly inefficient, as you re-derive the same columns using `pd.to_datetime` numerous times. Moreover, it doesn't work, because `np.where(cond, df, mod)` applies `mod` in the `df` where `cond` is false. Instead of subtracting 100 from years greater than 2000, you subtract 100 from years less than 2000.